# Crystal Reports constantly has open connections to database server

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

I have Crystal Reports installed and working against Oracle server. When opening Toad and checking "Top Session Finder" I see that Crystal (cms.exe) constantly has open connections with the database.

Why does cms.exe create so much connections against the database? can it be limited? what is their purpose?

Can I set Crystal Server to open connection only when it needs them and close them when it's done using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cms.exe` process stands for *Central Management Server*, it is one of the core pieces of the Crystal Server platform.

*Why does cms.exe create so much connections against the database? can
it be limited?*

If you open the CMC (Central Management Console) and select *Servers* and open the properties page for the Central Management Server, you should see an option *System Database Con­nections Requested*.

The option's purpose, explained by the Administrator's Guide:

> Specifies the number of CMS system database connections that the CMS
>   attempts to establish. If the server cannot es­tablish all of the
>   requested database connection, the CMS continues to function but at a
>   reduced performance, since fewer concurrent requests can be served
>   simultaneously. The CMS will attempt to establish additional
>   connections, until the requested number of connection is established.

*what is their purpose?*

Again, taken from the Administrator's Guide:

> The CMS maintains security and configuration information, directs
>   service requests to servers, manages auditing, and maintains the CMS
>   system database.

In other words: your Crystal Server environment cannot function without the CMS. Shut it down and your whole environment stops working.

It always needs open connections to the database in order to serve requests quickly. While you can limit the number of connection, doing so might impact the performance of your Crystal Server environment.

Comment: Is it possible for cms to open a connection on demand? what I mean is open connection when it needs something from the database and close it when it's done?

Comment: No, the connections for the CMS need to remain open. It does not support opening and closing connections on demand. That's only supported with connections used for reporting. Having to continuously disconnect and reconnect would severely hamper performance and also put a larger strain on the database than simply keeping the connections open.